# Multiple databases (mongodb[mongoengine] and sql ) with django 1.8

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine with Django and my project needs to connect to one instances of MongoDB while another with sql .How my databse section of setting.py should be like ?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'admin_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    },

}

from mongoengine import connect
connect(
db='pom',
username='admin',
password='root',
host='mongodb://admin:root@localhost'
)
```

Comment: Which is your default database?? mysql or mongo db??

Comment: Are you using django-nonrel?

Comment: i wan to use both mongodb and sql databases. My default databases  is sql  and no,i am not using django-nonrel instead of that i am using MongoEngine

Answer (score 1):

You could add multiple databases for your app in your settings.py like,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'admin_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    },

    'your_desired_db_name' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME' : 'db_name'
}
```

For integration with mongodb, you may need to look up,

- [Django-nonrel](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine)
- [Django-MongoEngine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine)

Also, you may need to look up Django documentation for [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/)

Comment: i am using django1.8 and Django-MongoEngine is not used for django 1.8 so for integration i am using MongoEngine. so i need my setting.py file accoding to MongoEngine.

Answer (score 1):

MongoEngine does not support all Django contrib modules directly. If your projects dont need them (unlikely) you can use mongoengine directly. Otherwise you can also try

- [djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues)

Which seems to work fine with the latest Django version.

Comment: We are trying to use Djongo but it is not working as expected. I have posted an issue in your repo.

Comment: This does not look to be a problem with djongo, rather your script. Logging into admin is a basic operation. Works fine on my setup.

Comment: Please look at this question that I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700546/unusual-error-in-django-cannot-login-into-admin-after-creating-superuser