# Unusual error in Django. Cannot login into admin after creating superuser

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, djongo

This is a weird problem that I am facing in my Django application.

Configuration :

- Python 3.6
- Django 2.0.6
- DB : Djongo (MongoDB connector : [Djongo repository](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo))

I have overwritten the create_superuser to:

```
def create_superuser(self, email, is_staff, password):
    user = self.model(
        email=email,
        is_staff=True,
        is_active=True,
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

I am able to create the superuser successfully but I am not able to login into the admin page. Following is my traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 398, in login
    return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 62, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 58, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 62, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 58, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 62, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 58, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 66, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 141, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 179, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 174, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 377, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 404, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 195, in clean
    self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 70, in authenticate
    user = _authenticate_with_backend(backend, backend_path, request, credentials)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 116, in _authenticate_with_backend
    return backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 22, in authenticate
    if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 111, in check_password
    return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py", line 42, in check_password
    if password is None or not is_password_usable(encoded):
  File "/home/fractaluser/dev_eugenie/venv_eugenie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py", line 25, in is_password_usable
    if encoded is None or encoded.startswith(UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX):
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

This is very unusual (I understand what the error means) and I am not able to understand what is causing it or how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Were there other changes as well? I am not able to replicate this issue, if I change the `create_superuser` function to what you have posted, I can't even create a superuser. It just fails because the username is still being passed in, which is unexpected.

But if you did happen to get this to run, it looks like the `password` argument might be `None` which is causing the `set_password` function to call `set_unusable_password` according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password).

However, to dig down to what the problem actually is more information would be needed.

Comment: `encoded.startswith(UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX)` This is the problem. The password is going into this as encoded and I don't know why it is `int`. When I print it out, it shows an encoded password.

Comment: When you print it out what does it look like? Does it start with `"!"`?

Comment: Since this approach didn't work, I dropped using Djongo altogether. I don't remember the output now. Sorry!